# function to show purchase note in Woocommerce email deprecated

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to show the purchase note beneath the product in the customer_processing_order email that Woocommerce generates.

I have added the following to my functions.php file:

```
function sww_add_images_woocommerce_emails( $output, $order ) {

// set a flag so we don't recursively call this filter
static $run = 0;

// if we've already run this filter, bail out
if ( $run ) {
    return $output;
}

$args = array(
    'show_purchase_note'    => true,
);

// increment our flag so we don't run again
$run++;

// if first run, give WooComm our updated table
return $order->email_order_items_table( $args );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_table', 'sww_add_images_woocommerce_emails', 10, 2 );
```

This works, however it is printing an error message in the email stating the following:

> "Notice: WC_Order::email_order_items_table is deprecated since version
>    3.0! 
>  Use wc_get_email_order_items instead. in /nas/content/staging/ishgamultisite/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3853"

if I change woocommerce_email_order_items_table to wc_get_email_order_items the function doesn't work.

I'm hoping someone can tell me how I should modify the code as I'm not sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace  `return $order->email_order_items_table( $args );`

with

```
return wc_get_email_order_items( $order, $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but if anybody is still needing to show purchase notes, then there's an easier hook:

```
/**
 * PURCHASE NOTE
 * Edits the email order items args to show purchase notes
 */
function ag_add_wc_order_email_purchase_notes( $args ) {

    $args['show_purchase_note'] = true;

    return $args;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_args', 'ag_add_wc_order_email_purchase_notes', 10, 1 );
```

The filter `woocommerce_email_order_items_args` contains the arguments for what to display in the order emails.

```
$array — Optional. (callback) => array( 'order' => $order, 'items' => $order->get_items(), 'show_download_links' => $order->is_download_permitted() && ! $args['sent_to_admin'], 'show_sku' => $args['show_sku'], 'show_purchase_note' => $order->is_paid() && ! $args['sent_to_admin'], 'show_image' => $args['show_image'], 'image_size' => $args['image_size'], 'plain_text' => $args['plain_text'], 'sent_to_admin' => $args['sent_to_admin'], )
```

Source: http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_email_order_items_args/

Tested with WooCommerce 3.6.2 and works fine.